# angular:How to fix this issue

Tags: angular

creating new project in angualr:
the steps are:
   ->ng new blogger(by creating folder)
   =>ng serve --o(for opening in server)but not working

Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

how to fix this ?
i tried the option : 1)npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular
2)npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
3)npm install

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **`@angular-devkit/build-angular`** as dev dependency.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Comment: i did this too--->npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...2.6.7","depd":"~1.1.0'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell-5559\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-06T08_50_44_548Z-debug.log

Comment: run npm cache clean --force

Comment: Please paste `packages.json` that has some invalid syntax.